# How to change <a> to <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm stuck with the following issue. On [my page](http://new.digital-ant.cz/klienti/) I need to remove the hyperlinks from portfolio elements (see image below).

[image: portfolio elemente]

The website is in Wordpress with Semplice template so I cannot go directly to the code but I'm stuck with jQuery. I tried to remove the `href` attribute from the `<a>` tag but no luck. The solution is probably in replacing the `<a>` tag with `<div>` but I wasn't able to do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: So you want to keep the elements but just disallow navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your special case I will use [jquery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/),

In your code you should call it like this to match the way your website is using jquery:

```
jQuery(function($){$('a').off();})
```

This will disable all events on all anchors, I think you will need to edit the selector with something like `'.thumb a'` to disable just anchors you want not everything on the page.

With this solution, no need to replace any elements which will cause I lot of styling issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to apply a css class you could disable pointer events:

```
.disable-a {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add div element after a element and remove a element.

```
$("a").each(function(){$(this).after("<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>")});
$("a").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to remove `href` from an `<a>` tag.

In HTML:

```
<a id="aTag" href="https://google.ca">ABC</a>
```

In Javascript

```
var aTag = document.getElementById("aTag");
aTag.removeAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, all of the "panels" have a div with a class of `.thumb-inner`. You could just get all of those `<divs>` and remove the parent`<a>` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumb-inner').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });   
});
```

Also the `<a>` tags don't have an `href` attribute now. So there is nothing to remove. That is why your page is directing to an unknown page.